# MT3608 is not switching for particular input voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

I have PCB printed a board that feeds a 12V led strip from either a Li-ion battery or a 5V USB. With no load, the output is 12V, as it should. As soon as I connect the led strip (80mA at 12V), the output voltage drops to ~8V, and the current drops to a few mA. The circuit also produces a distinct high-freq sound when a load is connected. However, the circuit works fine with other input voltages. Below is the list of working and non-working input voltages, and the current:

- Vin < 3.0: does not work (expected)
- 3.0 < Vin < 3.7: works, I ~ 450 mA
- 3.7 < Vin < 5.5: does not work, I ~ 20 mA
- Vin > 5.5: works, I ~ 240 mA

The current flows from the top to the bottom in the pic below. It's a one-sided board.

C4: 25V 22uF X5R ±20% 0805

L1: 2.3A 10uH ±20% SMD,5x5mm

D5: 40V 0.45V 5A DO-214AA Schottky

### Version 1

[image]
[image]

Questions:

1. why does it behave like this?
2. how can I fix it?
3. can I fix it without re-printing the PCB?

There are related questions:

- [MT3608 Improper Output Voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/477651/mt3608-improper-output-voltage)
- [MT3608 wrong output voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630287/mt3608-wrong-output-voltage)

but the former hasn't shown how far the capacitor had been placed in the beginning (is my cap C4 placed too far or acceptable?) and after he found the solution, and the latter seems to be not resolved, only hints.

---

### Version 2

After reading the replies, I updated the layout as follows:

[image]

---

### Version 3

Where possible, replaced tracks with copper pour.

[image]

---

### Version 4

Tight SOT23-6 footprint, removed R_EN.

[image]

---

Full project link: https://github.com/dizcza/flashlight_kicad

Comment: In your list of input voltages/currents, is the current value the input current at that voltage for the same 12V 80mA load connected on the output?
Also, are you able to probe the output voltage?

Comment: There is a very long way from C3 GND to U2 GND and even longer to R6 GND. Can you improve this somehow?

Comment: @LordTeddy yes, the list shows V and I for the same load (12V 80mA connected directly  to my adjustable power supply). I can probe the output voltage and that's how I noticed the voltage drop.

Comment: @Jens yeah, I think I need to do another schematic just to test it. But should also I add 100nF caps to both input and output not to mention that they should be closer to the U2 now? Should I add a bulky 680uF to the output as in the second schematic I linked as related? The value of the L1 inductor does not play a role here and I can still use the same, 10 uH?

Comment: @Jens Thanks for pointing this out: placing them physically close does not mean that the path to GND is short, I'll pay attention to this. Is this the only crucial mistake I made here?

Comment: @Jens your guess is absolutely right: I've soldered a thin wire to shorten C3 GND and R6 GND to U2 GND and that solved the problem. It's still 1 cm in length but seems to be OK even without extra 100nF caps, which might become needed for a more delicate load like MC. Write down your suggestion and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: *but seems to be OK* It is **not OK**. The regulator may "work", but if you measure its performance carefully, you'll see that it's at the edge, and conducted emissions that interfere with the rest of the circuit will be pretty bad. This layout should have almost no visible traces, only copper pours. Start by figuring out where the switching current paths lay. The area of those paths must be minimized as far as feasible, since they are radiators and parasitic inductors.

Comment: *that solved the problem* If you think so, your problems have only started, I'm afraid, since this will be failing in the field. The layout has to be scrapped, and re-done as per the datasheet, or using common good engineering practice. If the product will be used by technically-competent users who like opening things up, they'll probably stop buying your products if they see layout like what you show. I know I would. Power supplies, be it switching or linear, are fairly complex and novices almost always get them wrong.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica all right, I don't have an engineering background, I studied physics and interpret schematics by thinking of how electrons move which doesn't help much. I ain't selling this product. I made it a year ago for myself, my family, and my friends when we had a pretty bad situation in Ukraine due to frequent power station shutdowns and total darkness for hours. It's open source, please have a look at https://github.com/dizcza/flashlight_kicad, the idea is worthwhile but the realization could be poor. I appreciate criticism when justified. I addressed your comments.

Comment: It does behave weirdly (slowly turns on, sometimes the issue I described appears again after I manually shortened the paths), maybe because I glued the printed board to a wooden case with epoxy, which could have dissolved the traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very long way from C3 GND to U2 GND (red) and even longer, leaving the picture, to R6 GND (orange). This should be made drastically shorter.

[image: GND paths in the layout]

If the SW output is on, the current flows along the red path, if the diode is conducting the current flows along the yellow path.

These long tracks behave like additional inductors L2, L3 and L4. The MT3608 will read wrong values at the FB pin because the GND pin voltage is different from the GND potential of the capacitors. So the IC makes wrong decisions. The track inductance L2 adds voltage ringing at the IN pin, L4 at the output circuit.

The generated EMI from these large loops also is a mess.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the equivalent schematics - that's very educational. Shortening the GND paths manually, I noticed that in my case it's sufficient to shorten the R6 GND only, and shortening C3 GND to U2 GND is optional. I did both, however. "The MT3608 will read wrong values at the FB pin because the GND pin voltage is different from the GND potential of the capacitors" - I thought the C3 and C4 are just bypass capacitors, aren't they?

Comment: @dizcza The only "traces" should be to feedback components. The switching power path - anything connected to C3, L1, D5, C4, and U2 pin 1,5,2 should be copper pours, laid out for minimum distances between paths. There should be plenty of vias from top-layer GND pours to a ground plane on some other layer. *the C3 and C4 are just bypass capacitors, aren't they?* No. They are the capacitors through which the switching currents flow. Without them, the regulator will likely self-destruct for example. Their parasitics have direct impact on performance, and they are critical parts.

Comment: @Jens could you have a look if the updated layout doesn't have other issues that I missed? I'll be placing a new order soon and want to make sure this time it will work. Thanks.

Comment: Looks much better now. Do you use X7R capacitors?

Comment: @Jens no, they are rated X5R. I see that X7R are recommended but I really don't know if selecting X7R is crucial here. I'm trying to minimize the assembly price and for X7R caps I need to pay extra $3.00 because it's from "Extended Lib" of JLCPCB while X5R 22uF can be found in basic components with no extra cost. I've linked my full project with BOM.

Comment: I overlooked the datasheet statement: "X5R and X7R types are suitable because of their wider voltage and temperature ranges". I think it's safe to use X5R then.

Comment: @dizcza, you are still using thin traces instead of copper squares, as the reference layout suggests. The solid copper does not take any more space. Is there any specific reason why you refuse to follow the proven and verified layout?

Comment: @Ale..chenski *Is there any specific reason why you refuse to follow the proven and verified layout?* - Yes. There are even two reasons: (1) I don't want to use vias (no routes should be visible to the user - the front panel) and (2) the recommended layout misses an important resistor that enables the whole thing, and this resistor does not fit into their greeny layout at all.

Comment: Anyhow, I added some copper pours where possible.

Comment: @dizcza, your excuses should be rejected. First, the R11 is unnecessary, a simple short to Vin does the job since you are not using the EN pin function. Second, the feedback net can be easily routed without any vias. And note the red lines in the reference layout: your trace form GND pin2 to Cin capacitor is still too long and too thin. And your solder pad footprint for SOT23-6 is unnecessary "fat", which compromises trace fanouts. It is unlikely that you will reach the advertised 93% efficiency, which I guess is quite important when operating from a battery.

Comment: @Ale..chenski well, I guess you're right. I've been using the default Kicad SOT-23-6 footprint and haven't considered that it's flat, thanks for noting that. After changing it to a tighter footprint (found in Sparkfun lib) and removing the R_EN resistor, the final layout looks really nice. Sadly, I recently ordered 5 PCBs with v3 before I made v4, let's see if they work.

Answer (score 2):

When making high-frequency switchers, one should always follow "reference designs" and [recommended board layouts](https://prom-electric.ru/media/MT3608.pdf), due to presence of "[high-current loop](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/lit/html/SSZTBF4)s" in switching converters. Can you see the differences between your layout and the reference? I would also try to follow the reference BOM, because some overlooked parasitics of components may affect declared performance of the device.

[image]

Comment: For things like sensors and uC, I look at hardware integration files. And I did look at MT3608 datasheet but I didn't pay attention to the recommended layout (I thought why should I care about the layout for such simple things as step up/down regulators). How wrong could I be... I'm marking @Jens' response as the answer as he pointed out the issue first in the comments.

Comment: @dizcza Modern high frequency switching regulator performance is largely determined by the layout, especially the EMI performance. *why should I care about the layout for such simple things* They are far from simple, textbook simplifications notwithstanding. In a switcher, the layout is basically everything, and with the exactly same components the layout will determine whether the thing works well, poorly, not at all, or even self-destructs. Yup. The layout you have made is pretty much exactly what *not* to do :) Essentially every thing you could get wrong, you did get wrong :)